# Is moderator chat separate from normal chat? How do I view it?

Tags: support, chat, moderator-tools

I saw a post on the workplace stackexchange which had many edits and there was also an automatic message that moderator comments or discussion had been moved to chat.

I was able to view the edits that had been made for this post.
I was also able to view the normal chat for the post.

But I couldn't figure out if

a) the moderator chat was separate from the normal chat

b) if so, how to find it

b) whether I had the privilege to read it

What I wanted to understand was some of the motivations behind the edits, in particular when some edits were done and undone, then re-done and re-undone again back and forth. I'm assuming there was some discussion behind it and I wanted to better understand the reasons. I couldn't see any such discussion in the chat that I found, which led me to think that the moderators had a separate chat.

Comment: There *is* a special chatroom for moderators, but it's unlikely that this post was discussed there.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misunderstand the comment? It usually says something like *"__a__ moderator moved comments __to chat__"*, not "to moderator chat"…

Comment: Why is this question migrated here? Just because there was "workplace" mentioned? Moderators can move comments to chat on any site, should have migrated it to meta.SE.

Comment: @MaskedMan even though it's on-topic on Meta.SE too, it's ok to ask questions on per-site metas.  I think the assumption is that people are already here.  Questions get more attention on Meta.SE because it's a larger community, and sometimes we redirect people there if nobody here can answer.

Comment: @MaskedMan In addition to what Monica said, each site can handle their moderation differently. Moderators are able to create private chatrooms and while I'd assume that every site has at least one that they reserve for internal discussion, I wouldn't be surprised if some mod teams used another medium like Slack. There's no standard moderator chatroom that's created for every site.

Comment: If the question were asked here to begin with, then it makes sense. But it was *migrated* here, that felt a bit strange. Whoever migrated it would have known that this question is better suited to meta.SE, since there is nothing "workplace-specific" to this question (it is just an unimportant detail that the OP observed it here, but it could have been any other site). On meta.SE, it would reach a much wider audience, which also means that a future user with the same question is more likely to get the answer if it is on meta.SE than here.

Comment: I didn't know that different SE sites have their own meta. Also, I thought about this as a general functionality of SE, not being site specific, which is another reason I went to post on SE.meta

Comment: I agree. I think the evil mods are planning something...We must find out at once

Comment: This was originally posted on Meta Stack Overflow, not Meta Stack Exchange. I don't know why it was specifically migrated here instead of Meta Stack Exchange, but it was not originally posted on Meta Stack Exchange then migrated here as everyone seems to think.

Comment: Then I must have googled for "meta stackoverflow" and posted there thinking it was the same. Like I said, I only thought there was one meta site for all of the stack exchange websites.

Comment: @Tiny Giant I hope that the "everyone" doesn't include me because that is exactly what I am asking about!

Comment: @user985366 It was not a complaint against you. It is quite common for questions to be migrated to a more appropriate place, and hey, the StackExchange people too seem to be unsure if they are SO or SE. They first used to have meta.SO to cover general questions, then created a meta.SE, then changed the company name from SE to SO and back (or something). My concern was about why *this* was deemed to be the appropriate place to migrate to, and not meta.SE.

Comment: @MaskedMan That would only apply to you if you were implying that this was migrated from Meta Stack Exchange to here. As for the SO/SE confusion, Stack Overflow is the name of the company, Stack Exchange is the network. Meta Stack Exchange is the meta for the network, Meta Stack Overflow is the meta for Stack Overflow, and the Company. If something is about the network, it should be posted on Meta Stack Exchange, but it is acceptable to post it on a child meta that the user is comfortable posting on. Again, I don't know why it was migrated here, I was just clarifying that it wasn't [...]

Comment: [...] migrated to here from Meta Stack Exchange

Answer (score 3):

You've misinterpreted that comment. When we move the comments to a separate (newly created) chatroom, the system will post this for us:

> Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been moved to chat.

Where the "moved to chat" section is a hyperlink to that chatroom. All comments that were not deleted at the time we do the move are posted in that chatroom. Usually all moved comments are also deleted automatically. We sometimes manually undelete comments that are still relevant but that varies.

> I'm assuming there was some discussion behind it and I wanted to better understand the reasons. I couldn't see any such discussion in the chat that I found, which led me to think that the moderators had a separate chat.

That can mean a few things:

- there is an active meta thread about the question where people are coordinating changes
- there are people discussing the question in the [main Workplace chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler)
- after the edits were made the comments involved were removed by a moderator. We can only move comments to chat *once* and after that we tend to nuke anything that should have been put in the chatroom and isn't relevant (any more). I haven't seen this happen much or at all when it comes to a question that's still actively being edited though.
- there's an edit war going on and people aren't bothering to communicate but are just making the edits and rolling them back. This happens even more rarely here as disagreements over edits usually move to chat or meta quickly.

But really though, you'd need to link the specific question that prompted your post here for anyone to figure out what happened in that specific case.

Comment: This definitely answers what the OP was trying to figure out, but can you address the question in the title too? I know a moderator chat exists but I've never seen it, so it would be good to have public confirmation that it's only accessible to moderators.

Comment: @DavidK there are moderator-only chat rooms, yes -- one for the moderators on this site only, and one main one for moderators across the network.  We use these rooms to discuss things that can't be discussed in public, for example because they involve PII, or to get advice from other moderators on how to handle situations we're not confident about handling on our own.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks, I kind of assumed that was how it worked.